# Using a dictionary with NSUserDefaults in swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to learn about dictionaries and nsusersdefaults in swift. I wrote a small program that creates a dictionary of strings and uses that dictionary to populate a tableview. Next I save the dictionary to NSUserDefaults.  Everything at this point is working great.  It's when I attempt to pull the dictionary back out and use it that things go wrong.

Here is my complete code, the error is on the line myDict = userDefaults and the error is Cannot assign a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to a value of type '[Dictionary]':

```
import UIKit


// Create dictionary
var myDict = [Dictionary<String,String>()]


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(myDict.count)

    // Dictionary starts out with 1 item when new
    // so remove that one thing and create it if needed

    if myDict.count == 1 {

        myDict.removeAtIndex(0)

        // Put some stuff in the dictionary

        myDict.append(["name":"Bill","age":"39","sex":"male"])
        myDict.append(["name":"Nick","age":"8","sex":"male"])
        print(myDict)


    } else {

        if let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("myDict") {

            myDict = userDefaults


        }

    }

}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myDict, forKey: "myDict")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return myDict.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel!.text = myDict[indexPath.row]["name"]

    return cell
 }
}
```

Comment: My code didn't exactly get captured by the {} in the view above but it is all there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myDict = [Dictionary<String,String>()]
```

should be

```
var myDict = [String:String]()
```

at least in swift 2.0

For your problem it should actually be

```
var myDict = [String:AnyObject]()
```

because that is what you get from NSUserdefaults. When you access a value from a key in the dictionary you need to cast it to String.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this solution when I was searching and I tried it but it breaks all the rest of my code. I can no longer append or remove. I guess I have to append and remove differently then I am above?

Comment: in your code you have a list of dictionaries actually. Is that what you want? I think you want a single dictionary, no?

A list of Dictionaries would be `var myDict = [[String:String]]()`

Comment: I wanted a single dictionary that I can add groups of "names,ages,sex" to, or anything really and use it to populate a tableview with after storing and retreaving from nsuserdefaults. After changing my code to var myDict = [String:String]() all of my myDict.appends are broken. Sorry if I'm missing something simple, I'm still learning.

Comment: Now I get AnyObject doesn't have an append.

Comment: Ok, so easiest would be to convert your *group dictionary* to a class with properties and stuff them in an array.

In your case, you would need to go with `var myDict = [[String:String]]()` then and `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("myDict")` would actually become 
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("myDict")`

Comment: Please understand that you are placing an array if dictionaries inside a dictionary. That is what I think where your biggest confusion comes from.

Comment: myDict = userDefaults is back to complaining I cant assign anyobject to string

Comment: yes, that goes back to my initial answer. If you want to make that direct assignment you need to declare `var myDict = [[String:AnyObject]]()`

Answer (score -2):

Instead of setObject use the [sync method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667046/nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-setobject-forkey-not-working-for-multivalu):

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];        
    if (![defaults objectForKey:@"vesselType_preference"])
    {
        [defaults setObject:@"Dry" forKey:@"vesselType_preference"];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: he is asking for swift specifically, so why post an Objective-C answer?